# Which ratchet components are css only, and which components require ratchet.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ratchet-2

Which [ratchet components](http://goratchet.com/components/) require ratchet.js, and which are css only?

I've included ratchet in my ember-cli project using the ember-cli-ratchet npm module. Ember removes the need for ratchet's push.js, and I'd like to understand which components won't work if I use only ratchet.css and not ratchet.js.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not (yet) familiar with Ratchet, a cursory glance at their Github page (https://github.com/twbs/ratchet) shows JS implementations for:

- modals
- popovers
- push
- segmented-controllers
- sliders
- toggles

I would assume that the other elements are CSS-only.